# Multifunction printer scanning to network share not working

Tags: windows-7, scanner, scanning

I've had this problem on more than one printer, so I believe the issue is to do with the computer that I intend to scan documents to.

On two different multifunction printers (HP and Canon), I've attempted to set up scanning to a share on a Windows 7 machine.

In the printer's web UI, it gives me options to put the computer's hostname (or IP), the share folder, and a username/password.

It doesn't matter whether I use hostname or IP, the scanner cannot connect to the remote computer.

I **can** ping the printer from the computer. Permissions **are** set up for the username that I've set up.

I'm wondering if there is some sort of firewall or antivirus issue blocking the connection, but I don't even know where to start. There isn't dedicated software I'm using to scan, it's just a direct Windows SMB scan.

As far as error messages go, on one printer I got a generic "Can't Connect" error. On the one I'm currently trying to set up (Canon), I get an "Error 806", which is a credential error, but I am absolutely positive I have entered the credentials correctly.

Comment: Is this on a home network or domain? What is the printer make/model? Are they on the same subnet? Are there any printer firmware updates you haven't applied?

Comment: It is a home network, and I'm using a Canon imageClass 8580cdw. Both are on the same subnet and I have the latest firmware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made a few comments above, but in the meantime check your Windows Firewall. Is Port 445 open?

EDIT:

Digging deeper into Canon's site, I've found [the following](http://kbsupport.cusa.canon.com/system/selfservice.controller?CONFIGURATION=1011&PARTITION_ID=1&secureFlag=false&TIMEZONE_OFFSET=&CMD=VIEW_ARTICLE&ARTICLE_ID=34549):

**Blocked Ports and Programs**

In some cases, third-party security or firewall software may be blocking or restricting port traffic or programs causing unexpected results such as inability to install or loss of functionality. Check with the software manufacturer for information on unblocking ports or adding exceptions for specific programs.

The following are ports and programs necessary for your printer to function properly.

**Ports**

TCP 80

TCP / UDP 8611

TCP / UDP 8612

TCP / UDP 8613

UDP 3702 - (Windows 7 / Windows Vista)

The following port list applies only to models with memory card slots
TCP / UDP 137

TCP / UDP 138

TCP / UDP 139

**Programs**

IJ Network Tool

Default location

c:\Program Files (x86)\Canon\Canon IJ Network Tool\CNMNPUT.EXE (Windows)

/library/printers/canon/bjprinter/utilities/canon ij network tool.app (Macintosh OS X)

IJ Network Scan Utility

Default location

c:\Program Files (x86)\Canon\Canon IJ Network Scan Utilityl\CNMNSUT.EXE (Windows)

/library/printers/canon/bjprinter/utilities/canon ij network scan utility.app (Macintosh OS X)

IJ Network Scanner Selector

Default location

/library/printers/canon/ijscanner/utilities/canon ij network scanner selector2.app (Macintosh OS X)

MP Navigator EX

Default location

C:\Program Files\Canon\MP Navigator EX**\ mpnex**.exe (** refers to version number) - (Windows)

/application/canon utilities/mp navigator.app (Macintosh OS X)

Comment: I opened port 445 (Windows Directory Services) and also used the built in "Administrator" account to access the share, which seems to have done the trick.

Comment: Glad I could help! It's sad that Canon didn't make that stuff more clear in the documentation.

Comment: The information you found isn't even in the "Technician's Manual" that you have to dig for online! Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

To test for blocked ports, try [IsMyPortBlocked](http://www.ismyportblocked.com) which is a service from [Firebind](http://www.firebind.com).

IsMyPortBlocked allows you to enter custom TCP and UDP lists of ports to test for firewall blocking.  It's especially useful to diagnose PC based firewall app blocking.

Comment: This is useful, but in this application I'm dealing with LAN ports, not WAN ports. In this instance, I would use the `netstat` command to see if a local port is open.